# How to make the performance operator output insert into database in rapidmienr studio?

Tags: rapidminer

i want to insert data in 2nd picture into database. what should i do?
[home page process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPzW8.png)

[result of performance operator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6sNO.png)

Comment: As a hint for sharing RapidMiner processes: On the menu go to View-> show panel -> XML. This shows you the XML representation of your process, which can be more easily shared with your peers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to transform the output of the performance operator into a regular example set. For this you can use the `Performance to Data` operator, then you can simply store the data in the database (it can normally only handle regular tabular data)

Comment: If i use performance to data, it will only show the accumulate value right? how about i want to show all the (prediction and true yes no value )?

Comment: In this case, you can simply store the example set after the 'Apply Model' operator in the data base as well.